# BreezeJs - Using expand() when two foreign keys are related to a common entity

Tags: breeze, expand, entities

Say, I have two entities, `Movement (id, #fromLocationId, #toLocationId)`, *fromLocationId* and *toLocationId* being two foreign keys of the second entity `Location (id, name)`. I would like to write a Breeze query that retrieves all movements with location names related to *fromLocationId* and *toLocationId*. This is what I got thus far:

`var query = breeze.EntityQuery('movement').expand('location');`

When I debug it and check the first record, for example, I find out that it has a *location()* and *location1()* properties. I can retrieve the location name of *fromLocationId* from `data[0].location().name()` but cannot do the same with that of *toLocationId*, as *location1()* is null. I even tried `var query = breeze.EntityQuery('movement').expand('location, location1');` but it is still not working.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Here are the .NET classes:

```
[Table("Location")]
public partial class Location
{
    public Location()
    {
        Movements = new HashSet<Movement>();
        Movements1 = new HashSet<Movement>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Movement> Movements { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Movement> Movements1 { get; set; }
}

[Table("Movement")]
public partial class Movement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int FromLocationId { get; set; }

    public int ToLocationId { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Location1 { get; set; }
}
```

In the DbContext class, the relationships look like this:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Movements)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Location)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.FromLocationId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Movements1)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Location1)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ToLocationId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out what I needed to do. Here is the solution:

`var query = breeze.EntityQuery('movement').expand('location, location')`

I guess, Breeze understands this as, the first *location* in the `expand()` will be related to *fromLocationId* and the second *location* will be related to *toLocationId*. In other words, add as many `entity` as foreign keys related to that common entity.

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: I don't think so. Something else is going on. What are the names of the navigation properties on the server? What is the metadata for the `movement` type (and is it really called that or is it called `Movement`?)?

Comment: As the question states, the entities are `Movement` and `Location` (as on the server). The properties of `Location` are *Id* and *Name*, and those of `Movement` are *Id*, *FromLocationId* and *ToLocationId*. The properties *FromLocationId* and *ToLocationId* are foreign keys that both point to `Location`. And you seem to be right, since BreezeJs does not retrieve all names corresponding to those two foreign keys. What do I do?

Comment: You didn't describe your backend technologies. Are you using EF?

Comment: @Ward: Yes, I am using EF 1.6.1 and Breeze WebApi2 1.5.2

Comment: I believe you need two navigation properties to go with your two FKs. Could they be named `FromLocation` and `ToLocation`? You'll need some EF configuration too (either attributes or fluent API) so that EF knows which FK goes with which property. Show us your .NET classes (and fluent API config if any).

Comment: @Ward: Sorry for the late reply. I actually meant, EF 6.1.1, instead by the way. As for the .NET classes, please view  them on the post. Thanks.

Comment: @Ward: Also, I have another problem. The load time of entities (with no navigation properties) that weigh more than 1.5MB is too long (usually 25 to 150 seconds), even when using the `.noTracking()` method. Those same entities are queried in less than 2 seconds on SQL Server. What could be the issue? Is there a way of reducing the load time significantly?

Comment: Have you measured time at each step? How long before the JSON arrives at the browser? Probably not THAT long. How many entities are in that payload? Are they entities? Should they be entities or just read-only data? You might look at the thread associated with my answer on [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677833/breeze-importentities)

Comment: Your EF modeling seems right but I'm not sure as I don't have anything comparable at hand right this moment. What happens when you test it with a LINQ query on the server side that matches your intentions with the Breeze query? I'm betting the `.Include('Location, Location1')` doesn't work there either. In other words, I betting you have an EF problem not a Breeze problem. Let's nail that down first, shall we?

Comment: Yes, let's do it. I'm all ears.