# Breeze importEntities

Tags: breeze

When my application loads, I am exporting few breeze entities and storing those in local cache so that later when I have to make use of those entities again, I import them back from local storage and execute the query locally.

There is one entity that has 84389 rows. I have noticed that the importEntites take longer to execute for this entity. Is there a way I can speed up this ?

```
var entities = manager.getEntities('Client');
var exportedEntity = manager.exportEntities(entities, { includeMetadata: false });
```

I am storing exportedEntity in cache.

I am importing the above exportedEntity into entitymanager after fetching from cache.

```
entityManager.importEntities(exportedEntity);
```

The above statement takes longer for the Client entity. The client has 80K rows in table. I am not sure if that reduces the execution speed for importEntities method.
I am also executing query locally after the entity is imported.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by one entity having 84389 rows.

Comment: I mean to say that the importEntity operation takes longer time to execute for an entity that has 84389 rows (large amount of data) in database.

Comment: Still not clear, in general a single entity represents a single row. The concept of an entity having 84K rows doesn't make sense. Do you mean a query that returns 84K rows?

Comment: I have added little code in my question. I hope that helps. I might be doing something wrong. I want to export all the 84K rows to store in cache and then import it back. Client is a table in database that has those no of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that you have an Entity**Type**, `Client`, with 84k rows/entities.

That's a lot of objects. I would reconsider whether that data should be treated as rich Breeze entities or if they should be held in a simpler, more compact form as data objects. I'm leaning strongly to the latter, especially if they are read-only. There is less benefit to representing read-only data as entities and, at these volumes, bad performance and memory usage are more likely.

Remember that not all data have to be entities and Breeze is happy to fetch a mix of entity and raw data. Hybrid apps are quite common.

If you still want to explore treating them as entities, you might try the following export command which outputs all entities of a given type as JSON:

```
var exported = manager.exportEntities('Client', {asString:false, includeMetadata:false});
```

The result can be imported as before.

```
var imported = manager.importEntities(exported);
```

This *may* improve export and import speed (or not).

You don't have to query locally afterward. All the imported entities are in `imported.entities`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try the asString:false parameter. I am executing the query locally afterwards because I want to apply sort and predicate parameters to my results before accessing it.

Comment: Once more I ask you to consider whether it is appropriate to treat these data as entities. You must also be cautious about attempting to JSON stringify and parse so much data and even whether they will fit in local storage. This isn't strictly a Breeze performance issue.

Comment: I tried JSON stringify but that did not affect anything. If not entities, can you suggest ways to treat Client data in the app ? Luckily for me, its read only data and as you mentioned that doesn't have to be breeze entities.

Comment: Not really surprised as the main difference is whether JSON.parse is called.

Comment: What is wrong with simply calling the endpoint for that data. Is this an `EntityType` defined in metadata? Why? If easy to exclude from metadata, do so. You can still hit the server endpoint w/ the `EntityManager` which will return the data exactly as received (not as entities). Or cut out the middleman and use whatever AJAX component supports your app (e.g, `$http` or `jQuery.ajax`). Then manage these data separately, perhaps as properties of your `datacontext` service.

Comment: I loved the idea. You can have mention this in the actual answer and I will mark it as an answer :)

Comment: I thought I did in paragraphs 2 & 3 but I may have been too subtle . Would appreciate the answer selection, thanks.